# How to wait for setState in componentDidMount to resolve when testing with enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a React component that runs some asynchronous code and calls setState in componentDidMount.

Here is my react component that I want to test:

```
/**
*
* AsyncComponent
*
*/

import React from 'react';

class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      component: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.component.then(component => {
       this.setState({
         loaded: true,
         component: component.default ? component.default : component,
       });
    });
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return null;
    }

    const Component = this.state.component;

    const { component, ...rest } = this.props;

    return <Component {...rest} />;
  }
}

export default AsyncComponent;
```

Here is the test case. I am using jest and enzyme.

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import AsyncComponent from '../index';

const TestComponent = () => <div>Hello</div>;

describe('<AsyncComponent />', () => {
  it('Should render loaded component.', () => {
    const promise = Promise.resolve(TestComponent);
    const rendered = mount(<AsyncComponent component={promise} />);
    expect(rendered.state().loaded).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

The test fails because state.loaded is still set to false. Is there a way I can make sure that AsyncComponent has fully loaded before calling expect?

I can get it to work if I wrap the expect assertion in a setTimeout, but that seems like a rather hacky way to do it. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Approach with `setTimeout` is totally fine. Since it's a macrotask, it will be guaranteed to be called only after microtasks queue becomes empty - in other words when all the Promises are resolved and `.then` is processed

With this approach your test will legitimately pass after (we assume all server calls are properly mocked):

1. You add more calls either in sequence `.then(...).then(... Another call).then(...)`
2. You replace server call with some sync operation(reading from Redux store or local storage)
3. Refactor component to function version with hooks

The only thing I'd change - instead of checking state data(that would not with to function components and is fragile even to class components), I'd check `.isEmptyRenderer()` that must be `true` before timeout(so until promises are all settled) and `false` inside of timeout

More on macrotask/microtask difference: https://javascript.info/event-loop

[UPD] as @Estus Flask noticed below, relying on `setTimeout` in generic case might lead to callback hell(`setTimeout` after first action, then nested `setTimeout` to do next step etc). To avoid that we can use

```
await new Promise(resolve => { setImmediate(resolve); });
```

to flush microtasks queue. Or use tiny [`flush-promises`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises) package that does the same under the hood but looks lighter:

```
await flushPromises();
```

Comment: FWIW, `flush-promises` does that exactly while keeping promise control flow; wrapping everything with setTimeout affects chaining and error handling. Additionally, it uses setImmediate which can be longer than setTimeout. It's not a hack but only when a dev has a good idea what happens and when, which is often not the case.

Comment: @EstusFlask I agree with you that `await flushpromises()` looks much nicer than nested `setTimeout`(when it's required - e.g. when we need wait for loading to end few times until reaching "state of interest"). But what's wrong with chaining and error handling if we use `setTimeout`?

Comment: It's not about setTimeout but the use of callback-based API in promise control flow - unless setTimeout is wrapped with `new Promise`, which is what flushPromises basically does. Jest naturally supports promises for error handling and test execution. Switching from promises to callbacks at some point prevents from that and contributes to callback hell. I mean that `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r)); await promise; ...` is ok, and `setTimeout(() => promise.then...)` is not.

Comment: yes, agree with you. I was thinking just in scope of OP's question where just single operation with async outcomes. Added to the answer to warn others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify jest about the promise either by using `async/await` or return the promise from the test, have a look at the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html#content)

```
describe('<AsyncComponent />', () => {
  it('Should render loaded component.', async() => {
    const promise = Promise.resolve(TestComponent);
    const rendered = mount(<AsyncComponent component={promise} />);
    await promise
    expect(rendered.state().loaded).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but the test fails with "rendered.state().loaded" still being equal to false.

Comment: Could you check that the callback in the promise is called?

Comment: `Promise.resolve(TestComponent)` resolves immediately with the component. It has nothing to do with `setState` and the component being ready for testing. This code doesn't make any sense and surely doesn't solve the described problem.

Comment: This is not correct. `Promise.resolve()` does not evaluate immediately, all the test code will run before the callback in the `componentDidMount ` call is called. For better understanding of the execution order of promises have a look at: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/ . The first example shows exactly this case.

Comment: Of cause the `async/await` looks like a hack, and the Jest team thinking about to a feature to resolve all promises like it does for `setTimeout` but so far this os one of the possible solution for this. The other would be to return the resolved promise and make the `expect` calls in a `then` callback

Comment: By `immediately` I mean at the end of current scheduling queue. But it doesn't matter because this code doesn't make any sense. `await Promise.resolve(TestComponent);` does NOT guarantee that your asynchronous task in the `componentDidMount` is finished.
The only correct solution in this case is to mock `props.component` and resolve it before testing the component. I recommend `sinon-stub-promise` which is not Promise A+ compatible but it makes Promsies synchronous for testing purposes.

Comment: Still not get your point. `props.component` gets a resolved promise, the `expect` call is done after the `await`. Do you mean that the order of the `then` call and everything that comes after `await` could be in different order. I created an bin (http://jsbin.com/galitanuqa/edit?js,console) that never shows such behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and I came up with some clumsy solution, I have some function call in componentDidMount and I wanted to check if that function has been called, so that code worked for me

```
const loadFiltersTree = jest.fn()   
const wrapper = shallow(<FilterTree loadFiltersTree={loadFiltersTree} />)
jest.useFakeTimers()
jest.runAllTimers()
setImmediate(() => {
  expect(loadFiltersTree.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Breaking a promise chain is a common antipattern. As a rule of thumb, a function that uses promises should return a resulting promise to chain, unless this causes a problem. This guarantees that there won't be race conditions when caller function chains a promise. One of reasons for this is improved testability. This also applies to lifecycle hooks like `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  return this.props.component.then(...)
}
```

Asynchronous Jest test should chain all promises in use and return a promise. `async..await` is a practical way to do this.

In Enzyme, shallow rendering allows to disable automatic `componentDidMount` call and chain a promise that lifecycle hook returns:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(<AsyncComponent component={promise} />,
  { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
await wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
expect(wrapper.state().loaded).toBe(true);
```

This can also be done with full rendering by spying on `componentDidMount`:

```
jest.spyOn(AsyncComponent.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
const wrapper = mount(<AsyncComponent component={promise} />);
expect(wrapper.instance().componentDidMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
await wrapper.instance().componentDidMount.mock.results[0].value;
expect(wrapper.state().loaded).toBe(true);
```

Comment: But such an approach would not work if `.then` is somewhere in the even handler. Also test will not pass if I r refactor component to function with hooks. And is not it "testing implementation details"?

Comment: Oh, sorry for necroposting

Comment: This is not a problem with events because event listener usually uses a promise from another unit, which needs to be mocked in unit tests, and then you have a promise from mocked implementation at hand that can be chained in a test as well. The same applies to hooks, the test can chain `promise`, possibly wait a bit with `flushPromises()` and then assert the state. It's true regarding hooks, they made Enzyme much less usable and are more focused on testing the behaviour and the use of `waitFor`. I don't consider testing implementation details a bad thing, this helps to detect problems early.